# Brakes still dont work

Tags: brakes, nissan, rogue

I just changed the brake pads and rotors on my 2020 nissan rogue and the pedal still goes to the floor, even after driving it the brakes feel the same as before i did the rotor and pads. Do i need to bleed them?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: When did the issue start?  Was it after getting work done?

Comment: By your explanation it sounds like the brake pedal was going to the floor prior to you changing the pads and rotors.  Were the pads and rotors in need of replacing? Common reasons for a brake pedal going to the floor include leaking or broken master cylinder, leaking brake line or caliper, or air in the brake lines.  Since brakes are a critical safety component for you and others on the road you might want to take it to your local mechanic to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If no faults/leakage can be detected...
Small addition to your former answer: over time your brake fluid will change as it is 'hygroscopic' or absorbing water from the air. Since your brakes (clamps/discs (rotors)) will continuously change in temperature, air (with water vapour) will enter the liquid system, making your braking become 'sponge feeling' over time. It's worth to replace (pump through) new brake fluid. You'll notice the braking will become much harder & responsive.
For the same reason, don't buy too much as once you opened a new tin of brake fluid, the rest will go off in time. Disregard your (old of redundant) oil at your local 'reclamation yard' and when spilled on your car, wipe it off immediately as it will damage you lacquered parts. Good luck.